# What are the purposes of granulocytes in acute inflammation?

Tags: immunology, pathology, inflammation

I heard the phrase

> Neutrophilic leucocytes are kings in the acute inflammation.

Neutrophils are granulocytes, while leucocytes are not granulocytes.
I think this statement refers to the fact that leucocytes have neutrophilic properties, instead of being neutrophils itself.

Acute inflammation players are, I think

```
Granulocytes, monocytes and leucocytes
```

while in chronic inflammation similar player but the main factor is macrophages so the phrase which I heard

> Macrophages are the kings of chronic inflammation.

I think granulocytes are related to the Healing and Proliferation.
Eosinophils for instance in the allergic responses of acute inflammation.
I think granulocytes are phagocytosed by the macrophages and this way spread their functions through macrophages around.
Probably, neutrophiles are attached to the leucocytes such that they spread their function through leucocytes (so called neutrophilic leucocytes).

Let's cover first this, since we can after understanding it go to the chronic one.
**What is the purposes of granulocytes in acute inflammation?**

Comment: Have you read the WP article on [neutrophilic granulocytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrophil_granulocyte), the most abundant form? Essentially, they are the first infiltrating cells to arrive at the site of injury at the beginning of acute inflammation (bacterial infection, environmental exposure, etc.).

Comment: How are neutrophilic granulocytes related to neutrophilic leucocytes?

Comment: As far as I know they are the same thing. Neutrophilic granulocytes is another term (usually) for neutrophils. All granulocytes (white blood cells with granules in the cytoplasm) are leukocytes (or leucocytes), which literally means "white cells." Another term is polymorphonuclear leukocyte, which refers to neutrophils' unusual nucleus, generally having 2-5 lobes or sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MattDMo's answer

> Essentially, [neutrophilic granulocytes] are the first infiltrating
>   cells to arrive at the site of injury at the beginning of acute
>   inflammation (bacterial infection, environmental exposure, etc.).

which I agree with.